# Creating subnets and assinging rout tables to them

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform and I'm trying to create a VPC with multiple subnets and adding route tables to all those subnets in a for loop manner.

VPC: `10.207.0.0/16`

There's `number_of_subnets` which will create subnets like this: `10.207.x.0/24`

This code works fine:

```
variable "region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}

variable "availability_zone" {
  default = "us-east-1a"
}

variable "cidr_block" {
  default = "207"
}

variable "number_of_subnets" {
  default = 5
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

resource "aws_vpc" "test_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.${var.cidr_block}.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy     = "default"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "test_vpc_${var.cidr_block}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "test_subnets" {
  count                   = var.number_of_subnets
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.test_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.${var.cidr_block}.${count.index+1}.0/24" # start from x.x.1.0/24
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zone
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags = {
    Name = "test_subnet_${var.cidr_block}_${count.index+1}"
  }
}
```

Now if I try to add this code to the bottom of the same file (everything is in one file called main.tf) to get the subnets and add route table to each:

```
# get all subnet IDs
data "aws_subnets" "q_subnets" {
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [aws_vpc.test_vpc.id]
  }
}

# add route table to all subnets
resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt_assoc_subnet" {
  depends_on = [aws_subnet.test_subnets]
  for_each       = toset(data.aws_subnets.q_subnets.ids)
  subnet_id      = each.value
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.test_rt.id
}
```

and run `terraform apply` it will give this error:

```
invalid for_each argument...
The "for_each" value depends on resource attribute that cannot be deteremined until apply,...
```

which doesn't make scense. First create vpc, then subnet, then get all subnets...

I also tried `depends_on` and didn't help.

How would I write this to make it work?

Any help is appreciated.

## UPDATE1:

I tried to use `aws_subnet.test_subnets.*.id` instead of data and it still gives depencendy error:

```
variable "region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}

variable "availability_zone" {
  default = "us-east-1a"
}

variable "cidr_block" {
  default = "207"
}

variable "number_of_subnets" {
  default = 5
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

resource "aws_vpc" "test_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.${var.cidr_block}.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy     = "default"
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "test_vpc_${var.cidr_block}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "test_rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.test_vpc.id
  route = []

  tags = {
    Name = "test_rt_${var.cidr_block}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "test_subnets" {
  count                   = var.number_of_subnets
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.test_vpc.id
  cidr_block              = "10.${var.cidr_block}.${count.index+1}.0/24" # start from x.x.1.0/24
  availability_zone       = var.availability_zone
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags = {
    Name = "test_subnet_${var.cidr_block}_${count.index+1}"
  }
}

output "subnets" {
    value = aws_subnet.test_subnets.*.id
}

# add route table to all subnets
resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt_assoc_subnet" {
  depends_on     = [aws_subnet.test_subnets]
  for_each       = toset(aws_subnet.test_subnets.*.id)
  subnet_id      = each.value
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.test_rt.id
}
```

is there another way to pass the subnets to `aws_route_table_association` without getting dependency error?

Comment: That is how `for_each` works, the values have to be known in advance: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#limitations-on-values-used-in-for_each

Comment: Btw, are those in the same directory/root module/module? I mean the subnets as well as the route table?

Comment: You can avoid the use of data source? And pass directly `aws_subnet.test_subnets` to `for_each` meta-argument

Comment: @DaniloCacace The issue here is that subnets were created with `count`, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkoE i was thinking the problem is the for_each on a data source because the documentation say "the for_each value must be known before Terraform performs any remote resource actions."

Comment: Yup, that is one part of the problem, I think the second part is that subnets are using count and route table for each, so both woulf have to be fixed IMO.

Comment: I tried to create a module for the ```aws_route_table_association``` but it still says the same error. Is there any other way to have a for loop?

Comment: Yes, but it depends what you want to do. Are those different modules, same module?

Comment: They were in one file, main.tf. I also tried to separate ```aws_route_table_association``` in a module but it still gives the same error.

having it in the same file would be better I guess.

Comment: I added Update1 section to the first post with the new main.tf (one file) which still gives dependency error.
Is there another way to pass the subnets to aws_route_table_association without getting dependency error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `count`, it is very hard to make `count` work with `for_each`. It would be better to continue using `count` for route table association as well. If you decide to go down that route, the only change you need is:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt_assoc_subnet" {
  count          = var.number_of_subnets
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.test_subnets.*.id[count.index]
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.test_rt.id
}
```

This will work as intended. However, if you must use `for_each` I would suggest defining a variable that could be used with it in all the resources you are now using `count`. If you really want to use `for_each` with the current code, then you can use the `-target` option [1]:

```
terraform apply -target=aws_vpc.test_vpc -target=aws_route_table.test_rt -target=aws_subnet.test_subnets
```

When running this command, this will be shown in the command output:

```
│ Warning: Resource targeting is in effect
│
│ You are creating a plan with the -target option, which means that the result of this plan may not represent all of the changes requested by the current
│ configuration.
│
│ The -target option is not for routine use, and is provided only for exceptional situations such as recovering from errors or mistakes, or when Terraform
│ specifically suggests to use it as part of an error message.
```

After the targeted resources are created, you could re-run `terraform apply` and it should create the route table associations.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/plan#target-address

Comment: Thans a lot. This is very helpful. :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.